# How to plot timeline chart with start and end date columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table

I have a table like this:

```
| Resource    | %   | Start      | End        |
|-------------|-----|------------|------------|
| John        | 0.1 | 10/1/2018  | 11/15/2018 |
| Paul        | 0.2 | 8/20/2018  | 11/30/2018 |
| Jeremy      | 0.4 | 9/16/2018  | 12/18/2018 |
| Lucas       | 0.8 | 11/23/2018 | 12/15/2018 |
| Paul        | 0.8 | 9/1/2018   | 1/31/2018  |
| Jeremy      | 0.3 | 9/1/2018   | 1/31/2018  |
| John        | 0.5 | 10/16/2018 | 11/20/2018 |
```

How can I plot a line chart to plot Sum % (Y axis), GROUP BY Resource (Series) for the period start to end (X axis), for each Item, so that I can see how much % of the resource is allocated in any day/month/year?

Pivot table/charts or any ideas are all welcomed. Thank you!